# Two rings carrying opposite current directions

Tags: electromagnetism

Suppose I placed a conducting ring on the ground with clockwise current, and then above it a second similar ring carrying CCW current.

Wouldn't the repulsion between the two rings get the top ring to hover unsupported?

If so:

1. would this be a stable or unstable balance, in terms of small horizontal movements?
2. in equilibrium, what would be the relationship between the ring's mass, spacing, and current applied?

Comment: The Earnshaw theorem tells you the configuration will be unstable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't given us a diagram, but I'm guessing you mean to coaxial rings like this:

[image: Coaxial rings]

Assuming this is correct then this is a fairly standard calculation that is easily Googleable. For example [I found quite a nice derivation here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tEYSUegp9WYC&pg=PA399&lpg=PA399&dq=repulsion%20rings%20coaxial%20current&source=bl&ots=MCD40YYYdv&sig=Tl3yQ9le09TlDNECbAu3l8lGy30&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDQQ6AEwA2oVChMIgsathtrxxwIViGsUCh35kQeI#v=onepage&q=repulsion%20rings%20coaxial%20current&f=false). The force between the rings is given by:

$$ F = \frac{3\mu_0\pi I^2}{2} \left(\frac{r}{h}\right)^4 \tag{1} $$

The force is attractive if both currents flow in the same direction and repulsive if both currents flow in the opposite direction.

So you are quite correct that if we fix the bottom ring then the top ring can be made to hover above it. If the mass of the top ring is $m$ then the downward force due to gravity is $mg$, so the distance between the rings is obtained by setting equation (1) equal to $mg$ and solving for $h$.

Comment: Isn't the force acting in a horizontal direction? Lorentz force, magnetic field upward and current towards left, so how can the force be directed upwards?

Comment: You have not considered the direction of the vector in your answer. In this case, B and mg are along y axis and i along x axis in the xz plane. Thus, force is along z axis and it is horizontal, so it cannot support the current loop.

Comment: @John, have you got a quick but rigorous way to decide on the stability of the equilibrium?

Comment: @Emilio, there's no configuration of stationary, static magnetic fields that can levitate in a stable manner. Diamagnetic materials (frogs, superconductors), electronic stabilisation, and continuously moving are the only three ways, and I've only seen the last discussed theoretically

Comment: As opposed the the first two, which I've seen in practise too

Comment: @EmilioPisanty: I dodged that question :-) It's pretty obvious that it's an unstable equilibrium, but I can't think of a quick and easy way to show that.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury: did you read the derivation in the book I linked? As I've drawn the diagram drawn the force is vertical, so it will either push the top loop up or down depending on the relative direction of the currents.

Comment: The diagram is a little deceiving, the equation given is for the case h>>r  (h much greater than r). So if h is less than or equal to r definitely do not use this equation!